# language not recognized: '-fobjc-link-runtime' linker error

Tags: xcode, linker-errors

I keep getting this error

```
    Ld "/Users/Justin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/House_Defender-egpzlctivcelfbbmefwjdphmrmtr/Build/Intermediates/House Defender.build/Debug-iphoneos/House Defender.build/Objects-normal/armv7/House Defender" normal armv7
cd "/Users/Justin/Dropbox/BLMSRC/House Defender/2.0 2/House Defender"
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.0
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk -L/Users/Justin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/House_Defender-egpzlctivcelfbbmefwjdphmrmtr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos "-L/Users/Justin/Dropbox/BLMSRC/House Defender/2.0 2/House Defender/House Defender/facebook-ios-sdk" 
"-L/Users/Justin/Dropbox/BLMSRC/House Defender/2.0 2/House Defender/House Defender/Submodules/evernote-ios-sdk/UnitTests/3rdParty/OCMock" "-L/Users/Justin/Dropbox/BLMSRC/House Defender/2.0 2/House Defender/House Defender/GoogleAdMobAdsSdkiOS-6.1.4/Add-ons/GoogleAnalyticsiOS_2.0beta3/Library" "-L/Users/Justin/Dropbox/BLMSRC/House Defender/2.0 2/House Defender/House Defender/GoogleAdMobAdsSdkiOS-6.1.4" 
 "-L/Users/Justin/Dropbox/BLMSRC/House Defender/2.0 2/House Defender/House Defender/Chilkat" "-L/Users/Justin/Dropbox/BLMSRC/House Defender/2.0 2/House Defender/Submodules/evernote-ios-sdk/UnitTests/3rdParty/OCMock" "-L/Users/Justin/Dropbox/BLMSRC/House Defender/2.0 2/House Defender/Submodules/ShareKit/Submodules/evernote-ios-sdk/UnitTests/3rdParty/OCMock" 
"-L/Users/Justin/Dropbox/BLMSRC/House Defender/2.0 2/House Defender/House Defender/AdWhirl/GoogleAdMobAdsSdkiOS-6.1.4" 
"-L/Users/Justin/Dropbox/BLMSRC/House Defender/2.0 2/House Defender/House Defender/libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSdkiOS-6.1.4" 
-F/Users/Justin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/House_Defender-egpzlctivcelfbbmefwjdphmrmtr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist "/Users/Justin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/House_Defender-egpzlctivcelfbbmefwjdphmrmtr/Build/Intermediates/House Defender.build/Debug-iphoneos/House Defender.build/Objects-normal/armv7/House Defender.LinkFileList" 
-dead_strip -v -lz -ObjC -all_load -x -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -framework SystemConfiguration -framework MediaPlayer -framework MessageUI -framework Security -framework Twitter -framework CFNetwork -framework iAd -framework AddressBook -framework MapKit -lz -lsqlite3 -framework StoreKit 
/Users/Justin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/House_Defender-egpzlctivcelfbbmefwjdphmrmtr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libShareKit.a -lGoogleAdMobAds -framework QuartzCore 
-framework OpenGLES -framework OpenAL -framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework GameKit -lchilkatIos -o "/Users/Justin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/House_Defender-egpzlctivcelfbbmefwjdphmrmtr/Build/Intermediates/House Defender.build/Debug-iphoneos/House Defender.build/Objects-normal/armv7/House Defender"

clang: error: language not recognized: '-fobjc-link-runtime'
```

I have looked everywhere with no answer.

Answer (score 0):

The linker command line shows an option "-fobjc-link-runtime", which cannot be recogonized. try to  find and remove that option from the "Linking" options in the build settings.

Answer (score 0):

According to the clang man page, -x must be followed by a language specification:

> -x language
>
> > Treat subsequent input files as having type language.